# Generate rows to fill in gaps between years, carry over value from previous year

Tags: sql, oracle, time-series, oracle18c

I have a table of road condition ratings (roads are rated from 1-20; 20 being good).

```
with road_inspections 
(road_id, year, cond) as (

select 1, 2009,   17 from dual union all
select 1, 2011,   16 from dual union all
select 1, 2015,   14 from dual union all
select 1, 2016, 18.3 from dual union all
select 1, 2019, 18.1 from dual union all

select 2, 2013, 17.5 from dual union all
select 2, 2016,   18 from dual union all
select 2, 2019,   18 from dual union all
select 2, 2022,   18 from dual union all

select 3, 2022,   20 from dual)


select * from road_inspections

   ROAD_ID       YEAR       COND
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2009         17
         1       2011         16
         1       2015         14
         1       2016       18.3
         1       2019       18.1
         2       2013       17.5
         2       2016         18
         2       2019         18
         2       2022         18
         3       2022         20
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b13316d15615a3566d0a7ef9b636aeb3)

In a query, for each road, I want to generate rows to fill in the gaps between the years.

1. For a given road, starting at the first row (the earliest inspection), there should be consecutive rows for each year all the way to the current year (the sysdate year; currently 2022).
2. For the filler rows, I want carry over the condition rating from the last known inspection.

The result would look like this:

```
   ROAD_ID       YEAR       COND
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2009         17
         1       2010         17 *
         1       2011         16
         1       2012         16 *
         1       2013         16 *
         1       2014         16 *
         1       2015         14
         1       2016       18.3
         1       2017       18.3 *
         1       2018       18.3 *
         1       2019       18.1
         1       2020       18.1 *
         1       2021       18.1 *
         1       2022       18.1 *

         2       2013       17.5
         2       2014       17.5 *
         2       2015       17.5 *
         2       2016         18
         2       2017         18 *
         2       2018         18 *
         2       2019         18
         2       2020         18 *
         2       2021         18 *
         2       2022         18

         3       2022         20

*=filler row
```

---

**Question:**

How can I create those filler rows using an Oracle SQL query?

(My priorities are: simplicity first, performance second.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function with a `LATERAL` joined hierarchical query to generate the missing rows from each row until the next row:

```sql
SELECT r.road_id,
       y.year,
       r.cond
FROM   ( SELECT r.*,
                LEAD(year, 1, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) + 1)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY road_id ORDER BY year) AS next_year
         FROM   road_inspections r
       ) r
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT r.year + LEVEL - 1 AS year
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY r.year + LEVEL - 1 < r.next_year
       ) y
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE road_inspections (road_id, year, cond) as 
select 1, 2009,   17 from dual union all
select 1, 2011,   16 from dual union all
select 1, 2015,   14 from dual union all
select 1, 2016, 18.3 from dual union all
select 1, 2019, 18.1 from dual union all
select 2, 2013, 17.5 from dual union all
select 2, 2016,   18 from dual union all
select 2, 2019,   18 from dual union all
select 2, 2022,   18 from dual union all
select 3, 2022,   20 from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | ROAD_ID | YEAR | COND |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2009 | 17 |
> | 1 | 2010 | 17 |
> | 1 | 2011 | 16 |
> | 1 | 2012 | 16 |
> | 1 | 2013 | 16 |
> | 1 | 2014 | 16 |
> | 1 | 2015 | 14 |
> | 1 | 2016 | 18.3 |
> | 1 | 2017 | 18.3 |
> | 1 | 2018 | 18.3 |
> | 1 | 2019 | 18.1 |
> | 1 | 2020 | 18.1 |
> | 1 | 2021 | 18.1 |
> | 1 | 2022 | 18.1 |
> | 2 | 2013 | 17.5 |
> | 2 | 2014 | 17.5 |
> | 2 | 2015 | 17.5 |
> | 2 | 2016 | 18 |
> | 2 | 2017 | 18 |
> | 2 | 2018 | 18 |
> | 2 | 2019 | 18 |
> | 2 | 2020 | 18 |
> | 2 | 2021 | 18 |
> | 2 | 2022 | 18 |
> | 3 | 2022 | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f64e4cf726b862c2ccf335d2025d0875)*

Answer (score 1):

```
with
  road_inspections (road_id, year_, cond) as (
    select 1, 2009,   17 from dual union all
    select 1, 2011,   16 from dual union all
    select 1, 2015,   14 from dual union all
    select 1, 2016, 18.3 from dual union all
    select 1, 2019, 18.1 from dual union all
    select 2, 2013, 17.5 from dual union all
    select 2, 2016,   18 from dual union all
    select 2, 2019,   18 from dual union all
    select 2, 2022,   18 from dual union all
    select 3, 2022,   20 from dual
  )
, prep (road_id, first_year) as (
    select road_id, min(year_)
    from   road_inspections
    group  by road_id
  )
, all_years (road_id, year_) as (
    select p.road_id, l.year_
    from   prep p cross join lateral (
        select  first_year + level - 1 as year_
        from    dual
        connect by level <= 2022 - first_year + 1
    ) l
  )
select road_id, year_,
       last_value(ri.cond ignore nulls) over 
           (partition by road_id order by year_) as cond
from   all_years ay left outer join road_inspections ri using (road_id, year_)
;
```

The first subquery, `prep`, finds the first year for each road id. This is used in the `all_years` subquery to generate all the years relevant for each road id.

Then left-outer-join to the original cata, copy the `cond` wherever it is available, and use the analytic function `last_value` with the `ignore nulls` option to fill in the gaps.

Note that I changed the column name `year` to `year_` (with a trailing underscore); `year` is an Oracle keyword, not a good choice for a column name.

Output:

```
   ROAD_ID      YEAR_       COND
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2009         17
         1       2010         17
         1       2011         16
         1       2012         16
         1       2013         16
         1       2014         16
         1       2015         14
         1       2016       18.3
         1       2017       18.3
         1       2018       18.3
         1       2019       18.1
         1       2020       18.1
         1       2021       18.1
         1       2022       18.1
         2       2013       17.5
         2       2014       17.5
         2       2015       17.5
         2       2016         18
         2       2017         18
         2       2018         18
         2       2019         18
         2       2020         18
         2       2021         18
         2       2022         18
         3       2022         20
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `LEAD function` and `connect by LEVEL` row generator we can achieve the same. **[The DB FIDDLE here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3201c466eda285e5b69f5fadda1da50e)**

```
    with r as (
      select 
        * 
      from 
        road_inspections 
      union 
      select 
        road_id, 
        2022, 
        cond 
      from 
        road_inspections 
      where 
        (road_id, year) in(
          select 
            road_id, 
            max(year) over (partition by road_id) 
          from 
            road_inspections a 
          where 
            not exists (
              select 
                1 
              from 
                road_inspections b 
              where 
                a.road_id = b.road_id 
                and b.year = 2022
            )
        )
    ), 
    data as(
      SELECT 
        r.*, 
        nvl(
          lead(year, 1) over (
            partition by road_id 
            order by 
              year
          )- year, 
          0
        ) gaps 
      FROM 
        r
    ) 
    select 
      road_id, 
      year + level -1 year, 
      cond 
    from 
      (
        select 
          a.road_id, 
          year, 
          cond, 
          rownum rn, 
          gaps 
        from 
          data a
      ) connect by level <= gaps 
      and prior rn = rn 
      and prior dbms_random.value != 1 
    order by 
      road_id, 
      year + level -1;
```